# How do I replicate "from module import class" with __import__() or django.utils.importlib?

Tags: python, django

I want to import a class from python module.  The module contains multiple classes and which one I need is determined by a string at runtime.

Edit:  I'm using python 2.6.5, django 1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With judicious use of `getattr()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass = getattr(mymodule, myclass_name)
```

Comment: and then `myinstance = MyClass.__new__(MyClass)`

Answer (score 0):

Or **import**(module,globals(),locals(),['classname',],-1)